# Django Rest Framework HyperlinkedIdentityField Error (Requires request)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error after serializing a many-to-many relationship, which works fine without the URL but for some reason I am getting this error when I try to include it.

```
`InitiativeUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
```

Here are my views and serializers.

**Views.py**

```
class CreateInitiativeAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateInitiativeSerializer

class InitiativeListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    serializer_class = InitiativeListSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Initiative.objects.all()

class InitiativeDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    serializer_class = InitiativeFullSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'


    def get_object(self):
        initiative_id = self.kwargs["initiative_id"]
        obj = get_object_or_404(Initiative, id=initiative_id)
        return obj

    def put(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class InitiativeUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField(serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        kwargs = {
            'initiative_id': obj.id,
        }
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)

class CreateInitiativeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Initiative
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'image', 'goal']

class InitiativeListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = InitiativeUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField("initiative_detail_api", lookup_field='id')
    class Meta:
        model = Initiative
        fields = [
            'url',
            'name',
        ]

class InitiativeFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = InitiativeUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField("initiative_detail_api", lookup_field='id')
    class Meta:
        model = Initiative
        fields = [
            'url',
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'image',
            'goal']
```

This is the serializer that gets the information from InitiativeFullSerializer.

```
class ChapterInitiativePartialListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
initiative = InitiativeFullSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = ChapterInitiative
    fields = [
        'initiative'
    ]
```

The initial serializer/s which is called via the URL.

```
class ChapterFullListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
url = ChapterUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField("chapter_detail_api", lookup_field='id')
active_initiativeset = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_active')
school = serializers.CharField(source='school.name', read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Chapter
    fields = [
        'url',
        'id',
        'school',
        'name',
        'payee',
        'active_initiativeset'
    ]

def get_active(self, chapter):
    initiatives = chapter.chapterinitiative_set.filter(active=True)
    serializer = ChapterInitiativePartialListSerializer(instance=initiatives, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

Where in my code should I add `context={'request': request}`?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. You have to check your view classes. There is a method called `get_serializer_context()` which should add the request by default. See [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L131). I would check this first.